# Convert teradata table columns to comma seperated values

Tags: teradata

Need your help to solve a particular problem I am struggling with

I have a teradata table which looks like below.

```
Queryid Databasename    Tablename
101     DB1             TB1
101     DB2             TB2
101     DB1             TB3
102     DB3             TB3
102     DB4             TB4
.       .               .
.       .               .
.       .               .
```

I need the output in the below format.

```
Queryid    Newcol
101        DB1.TB1,DB2.TB2,DB1.TB3
102        DB3.TB3,DB4.TB4
.          .......   
.          .......
```

I am using TD13.10 and don't have XML services and also the TDStats function is not available.

Any help would be immense..

Thanks

Comment: Looks like a query analyzing QryLogObjectsV, what's the data volume you're going to process? And what are you doing with the result?

Comment: hi Dieter , I am trying to process 1 month's data ,  I am trying to generate a report where I have one row for each queryid and in that row i have my totalampcputime,responsetime and objects accessed by that queryid. if i have multiple rows for all objects accessed per queryid then the ampcputime and responsetime will be multiplied by the total number of rows and hence the final result will be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use with recursive. Although you would have to use another table to store the  and in the with recursive use that table to concatenate the values by rownumber.

```
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE temp_tbl AS (
 SELECT
   queryid                     
   ,databasename ||'.'||tablename                                                           
   ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY queryid ORDER BY queryid) AS rnk
FROM temp
) WITH DATA PRIMARY INDEX(parent_id) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS

WITH RECURSIVE test1(query,databasename,tablename,LVL)


AS
   (
    SELECT queryid,databasename,tablename, 1
    FROM <tablename>
    WHERE rnk = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  queryid, TRIM(databasename) || ', ' || TRIM(tablename),LVL+1
    FROM temp_tbl INNER JOIN test1
    ON queryid = query
   AND temp_tbl.rn = test1.lvl+1
   )
   SELECT query,databasename,tablename,LVL
   FROM test1
QUALIFY RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY query ORDER BY LVL DESC) = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Aritra .. Just some questions .. what do the following symbols signify  ... 1) temp (I am assuming this is the table which is used to store the data which is being processed , 2) not sure what PRIMARY INDEX(parent_id) means , 3) FROM <tablename> , what table should be used here 4) INNER JOIN rec_test , i couldnt find this table

Comment: @SRG .. yest temp is just a random name to the table i gave to store data. Primary Index is the index which i am defining on the volatile table temp_tbl. For concepts in primary index you can search in wiki/google. the inner join part will be test1 which i have edited, thats the recursive aspect of the logic which is helping to get your desired result. If this answer has helped achieved your goal pls accept it.

Comment: Thanks very much Aritra , will give it a try , just one last question .. u have mentioned in the recursive query SELECT queryid,databasename,tablename, 1
    FROM <tablename> , what does <tablename> represent?

Comment: @SRG .. it represents the table from where u r selecting ( again , a random name which i chose )